# Macros not appearing in MathJax

Tags: html, macros, latex, mathjax

I am unable to get custom macros to appear in MathJax, even when I copy/paste examples from the documentation.  Currently I have the following setup:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      RR: '{\bf R}',                // a simple string replacement
      bold: ['\boldsymbol{#1}',1]   // this macro has one parameter
    }
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

But when I try to use $\RR$ or $\bold{abc}$ I wind up getting output that looks like "f R" and "oldsymbolabc".

Otherwise everything else seems to be working fine, but I can't get macros to work.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in JavaScript, e.g. `\\bf`.

Comment: I guess it could also be that some other intermediary is stripping them, e.g. php. But that's not possible to say without more information.

Comment: The double backslashes were getting stripped out and replaced by single backslashes -- didn't even occur to me when I was looking at the generated HTML.  Fixed now; thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that was all.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger please consider adding an actual answer so that cjohnson may accept it and a) you get your reputation, b) the question is now longer shown in "unanswered" and c) those who face similar problem can see that the question was answered and find the solution.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.